# How to write a regular expression to retrieve genres from this string?

Tags: python, regex

If I want to extract a list of just ['Horror', 'Adult', 'Cult Movies', etc..] from this `class 'pandas.core.index.Index`, what would be best regex for this? Something that grabs everything following capital Ts until a closed bracket?

But then is that a bad approach, given "Television" starts with a capital T? What should the approach be here? I've never used regex before.

```
Index([u'variable[T.Horror]', u'variable[T.Adult]', u'variable[T.Cult Movies]', u'variable[T.Mystery & Suspense]', u'variable[T.Science Fiction & Fantasy]', u'variable[T.Western]', u'variable[T.Gay & Lesbian]', u'Q("Tomato-meter")', u'variable[T.Comedy]', u'variable[T.Television]', u'variable[T.Kids & Family]', u'variable[T.Classics]', u'variable[T.Drama]', u'variable[T.Art House & International]', u'variable[T.Romance]', u'variable[T.Special Interest]', u'variable[T.Animation]', u'variable[T.Documentary]', u'variable[T.Musical & Performing Arts]', u'variable[T.Sports & Fitness]', u'variable[T.Faith & Spirituality]', u'variable[T.Anime & Manga]', u'Intercept'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Why not just everything following a `T.` (including the period)?

Comment: is there a way to do 'everything following T. up until ]' ?

Comment: Sure: `T\.(.*)\]`. The parentheses denote the capturing group

Comment: What about `T.Mystery & Suspense`?

Comment: How about ```(T\.[^]]*)```. T followed by a dot followed by zero to many characters that are not a right bracket.

Comment: Without any sort of attempt at the problem, this question is rather too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=T\.)([^\]]+)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qT3iQ4/3)

Comment: what am i doing wrong here?

import re
reg = re.compile(r'(?<=T\.)([^\]]+)', testreginput)
print reg

testreginput is the string of that big code block in my question...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex within a list comprehension :

```
>>> import re
>>> regx=re.compile(r'(?<=\[T\.)([^\]]+)(?=\])')
>>> [regx.search(i).group() for i in mylist if '[' in i]
[u'Horror', u'Adult', u'Cult Movies', u'Mystery & Suspense', u'Science Fiction & Fantasy', u'Western', u'Gay & Lesbian', u'Comedy', u'Television', u'Kids & Family', u'Classics', u'Drama', u'Art House & International', u'Romance', u'Special Interest', u'Animation', u'Documentary', u'Musical & Performing Arts', u'Sports & Fitness', u'Faith & Spirituality', u'Anime & Manga']
```

This regex used [positive look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which will match every thins without `]` between `(?<=\[T\.)` and `(?=\])`.

Also note that as a more pythonic and optimized way I used `re.compile` to compile your regex outside your list-comprehension to refuse of compiling the regex in each iteration.